# XmlPullParserException Java/Android WCF Connection with KSOAP2

Tags: java, android, wcf, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Okay,

I have been at this for **HOURS** on end and have gotten absolutely nowhere with. I am trying to connect a WCF web service to my Android application, via ksoap2.

I used this link as a guide to help me: http://www.prandroid.com/2014/04/how-to-communicate-wcf-webservices-in.html

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.xxx.test;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test extends Activity {

    public class SoapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { //NOTE: LINE 27
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.dialog.setMessage("Checking in...");
            this.dialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try{
                WebServiceCallExample(); //NOTE: LINE 39 THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);
            tv.setText(test_string);
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()){
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }

    private String test_string;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        new SoapTask().execute();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void WebServiceCallExample() {
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String URL = "http://[IP Address]/MobileServicexxxxxxxxxxxx.svc";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "GetServiceOrders";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IMobileService/GetServiceOrders";

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

  /* Set the web service envelope */
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        System.out.println("Request::" + Request.toString());

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try{
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //NOTE: LINE 82 THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS
            //SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            SoapPrimitive sp = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            System.out.println("Response::" + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
            test_string = sp.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Testing");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XML

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" name="MobileService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MobileWebService"/>
<xs:element name="GetServiceOrders">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="resource_No" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="GetServiceOrdersResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MobileWebService" minOccurs="0" name="GetServiceOrdersResult" nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayOfserviceOrderCT"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MobileWebService" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MobileWebService">
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfserviceOrderCT">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="serviceOrderCT" nillable="true" type="tns:serviceOrderCT"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfserviceOrderCT" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfserviceOrderCT"/>
<xs:complexType name="serviceOrderCT">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_bill_to_Customer_No_" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_bill_to_Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_customer_No_" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_description" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_fix_By_Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_fix_By_Time" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_fixed_Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_fixed_Time" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_no_" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_order_Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_order_Time" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_responded_Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_responded_Time" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_response_Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_response_Time" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_transaction_Status" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="_your_Reference" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="serviceOrderCT" nillable="true" type="tns:serviceOrderCT"/>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IMobileService_GetServiceOrders_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetServiceOrders"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IMobileService_GetServiceOrders_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetServiceOrdersResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IMobileService">
<wsdl:operation name="GetServiceOrders">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IMobileService/GetServiceOrders" message="tns:IMobileService_GetServiceOrders_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IMobileService/GetServiceOrdersResponse" message="tns:IMobileService_GetServiceOrders_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMobileService" type="tns:IMobileService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetServiceOrders">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IMobileService/GetServiceOrders" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="MobileService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IMobileService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IMobileService">
<soap:address location="http://[IP Address There is no localhost]/MobileWebService/MobileWebService.MobileService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I run this code, I get the following *XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT* error message:

```
03-03 15:55:31.440 18414-18414/com.example.xxx.test I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-03 15:55:31.544 18414-18414/com.example.xxx.test W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.xxx.test-1/lib/x86
03-03 15:55:31.617 18414-18433/com.example.xxx.test D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-03 15:55:31.715 18414-18433/com.example.xxx.test I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-03 15:55:31.731 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test I/System.out: Request::GetServiceOrders{}
03-03 15:55:31.777 18414-18433/com.example.xxx.test W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-03 15:55:31.777 18414-18433/com.example.xxx.test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad79fe60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test I/System.out: Testing
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT Bad Request@1:12 in java.io.InputStreamReader@a96abe8) 
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:432)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2048)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(Unknown Source)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Unknown Source)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(Unknown Source)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at com.example.xxx.test.Test.WebServiceCallExample(Test.java:82)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at com.example.xxx.test.Test$SoapTask.doInBackground(Test.java:39)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at com.example.xxx.test.Test$SoapTask.doInBackground(Test.java:27)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-03 15:55:31.816 18414-18434/com.example.xxx.test W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-03 15:55:31.907 18414-18433/com.example.xxx.test W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-03 15:55:31.908 18414-18433/com.example.xxx.test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad79ff00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-03 15:55:32.065 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.988ms
03-03 15:55:32.777 18414-18433/com.example.xxx.test E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab812650
03-03 15:55:32.792 18414-18414/com.example.xxx.test I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-03 15:57:48.796 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.845ms
03-03 16:11:41.066 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.014ms
03-03 16:16:57.038 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.365ms
03-03 16:25:56.319 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.178ms
03-03 16:32:00.297 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.924ms
03-03 16:32:41.884 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.291ms
03-03 16:34:58.627 18414-18420/com.example.xxx.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.906ms
```

I've commented which of the three lines pointed out is which, so you don't have to.

This is something I really need help with, so I would be very grateful for any contribution.

Thanks.

P.S. **PLEASE** don't tell me "Look at this: (Stack Overflow link)", because I've already seen it and I cannot relate it to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was despite my wsdl saying it was version 1.2, I changed the soap envelope back to 1.1 and it worked fine. This is the line I changed.

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
```

I can now connect to the WCF service.

Thanks to **NOBODY** helping me out!